# create constructor string string1,string string2,string string3,Object object1

Tags: java, android, object, constructor

i want to create a class in my MainActivity:

```
MyCard customCard1 = new MyCard(cardTitle.getText().toString(),
                cardbuttonon.getText().toString(),
        cardbuttonon.getText().toString(),
        cardbuttonon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] url={"url"};
                new onoff(MainActivity.this).execute(url);
            }});
        mCardView.addCard(customCard1);
        mCardView.refresh();
```

but he say me that the constructor MyCard(String,String,String,Object undefined is.

How can i define him on my MyCard:

```
package de.heron.cloudbox;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.fima.cardsui.objects.Card;

public class MyCard extends Card {

    public MyCard(String title, String desc, String string, Object setOnClickListener){
        super(title, desc); 
    }
    @Override
    public View getCardContent(Context context) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_ex, null);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(title);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText(desc);

        return view;
    }
}
```

can someone help me by my problem?

why can i make it with 2 onclicklisteners:

```
MyCardXml customCard1 = new MyCardXml(cardTitle.getText().toString(),cardbuttonon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cardbuttonon),cardbuttonoff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cardbuttonoff),
                cardbuttonon.getText().toString(),cardbuttonoff.getText().toString(),
        cardbuttonon.getText().toString(),cardbuttonoff.getText().toString(),
        cardbuttonon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String[] url={"http://everhome.de/api/applive/", "8ef43502ad3dc04f87b4a48b993878c0","/" + KEY_ID,"/" + KEY_COST};
                new onoff(MainActivity.this).execute(url);
                }}

                ),cardbuttonoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String[] url={"http://everhome.de/api/applive/", "8ef43502ad3dc04f87b4a48b993878c0","/" + KEY_ID,"/" + KEY_COST};
                    new onoff(MainActivity.this).execute(url);
                }}

                ));
        mCardView.addCard(customCard1);
        mCardView.refresh();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but `MyCard`'s constructor isn't even using half its arguments, your variable names are bizarre, and your indentation is screwed up. Why is `MyCard`'s constructor taking a parameter called `setOnClickListener`? That name doesn't sound like it describes an object; that sounds like it describes an action.

Comment: Can you please share exact exception. Beacuse MyCard customCard1 = new MyCard(..) is not completely closed.

Comment: To elaborate on Ashish's comment: you're missing a closing parenthesis on the `MyCard` constructor call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor needs an **Object** as the fourth parameter. You are not passing an object in the fourth parameter when
you are constructing the object.This will solve the error

```
MyCard customCard1 = new MyCard(cardTitle.getText().toString(),
            cardbuttonon.getText().toString(),
    cardbuttonon.getText().toString(),
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] url={"url"};
            new onoff(MainActivity.this).execute(url);
        }});
```

Comment: but whats when i have another button with a onclicklistener

Answer (score 1):

you should pass `View.OnClickListener` to your `MyCard` constructor instead of `Object`

Change

```
   public MyCard(String title, String desc, String string, Object setOnClickListener){
        super(title, desc); 
    }
```

with

```
   public MyCard(String title, String desc, String string,  View.OnClickListener setOnClickListener){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change  your constructor like this

```
public MyCard(String title, String desc, String string, OnClickListener clickListener){

}
```